# Vue Jest test suite failed to run: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, babeljs

I've set up my Jest, and it runs properly. But when I create a test for a file that contains a spreadoperator the test suite fails.

I'm using Vue configured from the CLI with Jest.

**What I have tried**

I've tried adding the `babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread` as a plugin to the babel.config.js but this had no result.

I also tried adding the `@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread` as a plugin to the babel.config.js but this also had no result.

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@vue/app"]
};
```

package.json (jest part):

```
"jest": {
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.{js,vue}",
      "!**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "vue"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    },
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js?$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      ".*\\.(vue)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest"
    }
  }
```

component.spec.js:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Component from '@/views/xx/x/Component.vue';
import Vue from 'vue';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

describe('About component', () => {
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(Component);
  });

  test('is a Vue instance', () => {
    expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Error:

```
 FAIL  src/__tests__/views/x/Component.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    D:\projects\project\project-frontend\node_modules\@babel\runtime-corejs2\helpers\esm\objectSpread.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import _Object$getOwnPropertyDescriptor from "../../core-js/object/get-own-property-descriptor";
                                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier



      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:471:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:513:25)
      at src/views/xx/x/Component.vue:670:49
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/views/xx/x/Component.vue:810:3)
```

Comment: I am facing similar issue while running test cases in JEST and vue-test-utils. Have you find the resolution for your query ?

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In package.json 
make sure this pluging"babel-core" version up to ^7.0.0-0 that like under.

"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-0"
}

Answer (score 0):

The final step for me was  to provide correct env variables in jest config an explanation why it needs it may be found [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1879).Also make sure babel packages installed

Sharing whole config 
// jest

```
process.env.VUE_CLI_BABEL_TARGET_NODE = true;
process.env.VUE_CLI_BABEL_TRANSPILE_MODULES = true;

module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
    roots: ["<rootDir>/src/", "<rootDir>/spec/"],
    moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'vue','json'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    },

    transform: {
     "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
     "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest",
    }, 
   snapshotSerializers: [
   "jest-serializer-vue"
   ]
  }
```

// in package json

```
"@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.9.6",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.5",
"babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
"babel-jest": "^25.4.0",
```